# Why aren't public delegates accessible through class instances?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I recently discovered that if I have a form (say from2) which has a public delegate declared in it as such (I know the delegate is not attached to anything)

```
namespace SomeTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public delegate void mydelegate(string some);

        public Form2()
        {   InitializeComponent();}


        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        }
    }
}
```

Now if I pass an instance of that form to say another form (form1) as such

```
namespace SomeTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 fm = null;
        public Form1(Form2 fm_)
        {
            this.fm = fm_;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Why cant fm access the public delegate ?
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't we go like `fm.begininvoke(fm.mydelegate,"SomeParameter")` I know the delegate is not attached to something but I am just curious why a public variable is not accessible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A delegate is a type -- that's why you can access it from the class, but not from an instance.  Consider the case of an enum:

```
public class Foo
{ 
    public enum Bar { A, B, C };
    public Bar Baz;
}
```

Here `Bar` is a type, but `Baz` is an object -- so `Foo.Bar` is valid, but not `Foo.Baz`.  Likewise, if you have an instance `var foo = new Foo();` then `foo.Bar` is invalid, but `foo.Baz` is ok.

Your delegate type `mydelegate` is like `Bar` in this example.

---

If you wanted to add an instance of the delegate:

```
public partial class Form2
{
    public delegate void mydelegate(string some);
    public mydelegate mydelegateImpl = new mydelegate( arg => Console.WriteLine(arg) );
}
```

... then you'd be able to access `mydelegateImpl` from an instance of `Form2`.

Answer (score 3):

You can access it you just have to use the class name not the instance name.

```
namespace SomeTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 fm = null;
        public Form1(Form2 fm_)
        {
            this.fm = fm_;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2.mydelegate // Works.
            fm.mydelegate    // Won't work. 
        }
    }
}
```

Why? Because delegates aren't fields or properties. Defining a delegate inside a class is more akin to defining a class within a class. Did you know this is possible?

```
namespace SomeTest
{
    public delegate void mydelegate(string some);

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form2()
        {   InitializeComponent();}


        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        }
    }
}
```